# $\log_{49}({x^2})=\log_{2}({5x-8})$

Tags: logarithms

I need help with this problem.
$$\log_{49}({x^2})=\log_{2}({5x-8})$$

I've tried doing this:
$$\log_{7}({x})=\log_{2}({5x-8})$$
$$\frac{\log x}{\log7}=\frac{\log (5x-8)}{\log2}$$
$$\log2 \log x=\log(5x-8)\log7$$
$$\frac{\log(5x-8)}{\log x}=\frac{\log2}{\log7}$$
$$\log_x (5x-8)=\frac{\log2}{\log7}$$
$$5x-8=x^{\frac{\log2}{\log7}}$$
I'm stuck here. I did a Newton-Raphson and got $1.8489491136680562534$. I need a closed form solution, though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be doable by hand.

Comment: @ZAhmed ... so no closed form solution? :'(

Comment: Yes, may have not coped it correctly.

Comment: @ZAhmed no, I've copied it correctly.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+log%2849%2C+x%5E2%29+%3D+log%282%2C+5x-8%29) doesn't give a closed form.

Comment: No one will give any answer. Yes, numerical solution may be possible.

Comment: @PeterPhipps yeah, I tried it on WolframAlpha, but didn't get a closed form solution. I was just wondering if it was possible. My friend compared it to integrating $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: @ZAhmed using desmos and putting the function as the subtraction of the two sides of the equation  above, gives a unique solution.

Comment: To be more careful, the condition $x>\frac85$ ought to be introduced in the first step, and the condition $x\ne1$ ought to be introduced in the second step from the last. Otherwise, that solution obtained in the last step is merely a *potential* solution, in which case it needs to be verified by plugging it into the original equation.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the original problem was mistyped. If the equation

$\log_4(\color{blue}{9}x^2)=\log_2(5x-8)$

was meant, that has an easy solution ... if you watch your signs and remember that the argument of a logarithm must be positive (if you are working with real variables).

> With the proposed alternative, $\log_2(\pm(3x))=\log_2(5x-8)$, thus $\pm3x=5x-8$ and $x=1$ or $x=4$; but only $x=4$ gives positive arguments for both original logarithms.

Comment: I was on the Desmos Discord server when someone asked this, and someone did suggest that the author of the problem might have intended the question to be like this. This would be an easy solve, thanks for your help though! +1

Comment: Now, you have a serious problem to face. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you copied correctly, there is no closed form solution for the zero of function$$f(x)=5x-8-x^{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(7)}}$$ I suppose that, graphing, you noticed that the solution is just smaller than $x=2$.

Let $a=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(7)}$ and expand around $x=2$
$$f(x)=\left(2-2^a\right)+\left(5-2^{a-1} a\right) (x-2)-2^{a-3} (a-1) a
   (x-2)^2-\frac{1}{3} \left(2^{a-4} (a-2) (a-1) a\right) (x-2)^3+O\left((x-2)^3\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$x=2+\frac{2^a-2+f(x)}{5-2^{a-1} a}-\frac{2^{a-2} (a-1) a
   \left(2^a-2+f(x)\right)^2}{\left(5-2^{a-1} a\right)^2 \left(2^a
   a-10\right)}+O\left(\left(2^a-2+f(x)\right)^3\right)$$ which is the same as the first iteration of Halley method.

Make $f(x)=0$ as desired and $a=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(7)}$; so, you have an explicit formula and, converted to decimals
$$x_{(3)}=\color{blue}{1.8489}5718257\cdots$$ Do the same with Householder method to obtain
$$x_{(4)}=\color{blue}{1.848949}5426\cdots$$ while, as you wrote, the solution is
$$x_{(\infty)}=\color{blue}{1.8489491137}\cdots$$

**Edit** *(just for the fun)*

$$f(x) \sim 5x -8 -x^{\frac 1 3}$$ the solution of which giving
$$x_0=\frac{8}{15 \sqrt{15}}\Bigg[\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(12 \sqrt{15}\right)\right) \Bigg]^3=1.84531$$
which is a much better starting point for any Newton-type method or approximation.

Using the implicit function theorem
$$x_1=x_0+\frac{x_0^{a_0}\, \log (x_0)}{5-a_0\, x_0^{a_0-1}} (a-a_0)$$

Numerically, $x_1=1.84891$

Comment: One nitpick. I tend to favor blue over red for color because of the commonality of red/green color blindness. Still +1.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. May I confess that I do not worry about colors (I am blind). This is my wife's choice !! In spite of 57 years of marriage, I shall  obey you and no more her !

Comment: So how do you even render these things? 

Comment: @OscarLanzi. She is sitting next to me ! Take care since I did already did obey.